# c# Interop Array of Struct in a Struct using Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono, pinvoke

Been banging my head against a brick wall for a while now.

I'm converting some C++ code to C# under Mono on Linux. The Code is p/Invoking into a dll, but is erroring out.

The issue seems to be with an array of struct within a struct. The code I have so far is;

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct _AcceptorCoin
{
    public int         Value ;                /* Value of this coin */
    public int         Inhibit ;              /* Set by PC: this coin is inhibited */
    public int         Count ;                /* Total number read "ever" */
    public int         Path ;                 /* Set by PC: this coin's chosen output path */
    public int         PathCount ;            /* Number "ever" sent down the chosen Path */
    public int         PathSwitchLevel ;      /* Set by PC: PathCount level to switch coin to default path */
    public char        DefaultPath ;          /* Set by PC: Default path for this specific coin */
    public char        FutureExpansion ;      /* Set by PC: for future use */
    public char        HeldInEscrow ;         /* count of this note / coin in escrow (usually max 1) */
    public char        FutureExpansion2 ;     /* for future use */
    public unsafe char*      CoinName ;             /* The string, usually as returned from the acceptor, describing this coin */
};
```

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct _AcceptorBlock
{
    public int            Unit ;                /* Specification of this unit */
    public int            Status ;              /* AcceptorStatuses - zero if device OK */
    public int            NoOfCoins ;           /* The number of different coins handled */
    public int            InterfaceNumber ;     /* The bus / connection (This meaning / value has changed in 1.11.x) */
    public int            UnitAddress ;         /* For addressable units */
    public int            DefaultPath ;
    public int            BarcodesStacked ;     /* The total number of barcode tickets stacked by this acceptor */
    public string         Currency;                 /* Main currency code reported */
                                                /* by an intelligent acceptor */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray , SizeConst = 256)]
    public unsafe  _AcceptorCoin[] Coin;        /* (only NoOfCoins are set up) */
    public int            SerialNumber ;        /* Reported serial number (0 if N/A) */
    public unsafe char*   Description ;         /* Device specific string for type / revision / coin set */
    public int            EscrowBarcodeHere ;   /* If this is non zero, then the barcode reported by BarcodeInEscrow is from this acceptor */
};
```

I'm then declaring my P/Invoke to a linux library;

```cs
[DllImport("libaes_access.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "ReadAcceptorDetails")]     //This is an example of how to call a method / function in a c library from c#
public static unsafe extern int _ReadAcceptorDetails(int Number, ref _AcceptorBlock Snapshot);
```

And Invoking like;

```cs
_AcceptorBlock _Snapshot = new _AcceptorBlock ();
int intReturnValue = _ReadAcceptorDetails (Number, ref _Snapshot);
```

The full output I'm getting in the Application Output is;

```
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_string_new_wrapper (intptr) <IL 0x00021, 0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MainControl.AESControl._ReadAcceptorDetails (int,MainControl.AESControl/_AcceptorBlock&) <IL 0x0033a, 0xffffffff>
  at MainControl.AESControl.ReadAcceptorDetails (int,MainControl.AcceptorStatus&) [0x0000f] in /home/pi/csharp/ChangeMachine/MainControl/Helper Classes/AESControl.cs:599
  at MainControl.CashHandling.UpdateAcceptorDetails () [0x00033] in /home/pi/csharp/ChangeMachine/MainControl/CashHandling.cs:425
  at MainControl.CashHandling.InitAcceptorDetails () [0x00033] in /home/pi/csharp/ChangeMachine/MainControl/CashHandling.cs:404
  at MainControl.CashHandling.StartCashHandling () [0x0002d] in /home/pi/csharp/ChangeMachine/MainControl/CashHandling.cs:158
  at ChangeMachine.MainLoop..ctor (MainWindow) [0x00080] in /home/pi/csharp/ChangeMachine/ChangeMachine/MainLoop.cs:75
  at MainWindow..ctor () [0x0000f] in /home/pi/csharp/ChangeMachine/ChangeMachine/MainWindow.cs:37
  at ChangeMachine.MainClass.Main (string[]) [0x00006] in /home/pi/csharp/ChangeMachine/ChangeMachine/Main.cs:11
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:


Debug info from gdb:

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xb3de3430 (LWP 6758)]
[New Thread 0xb3e03430 (LWP 6757)]
[New Thread 0xb41ff430 (LWP 6756)]
[New Thread 0xb44b8430 (LWP 6755)]
[New Thread 0xb42ff430 (LWP 6754)]
[New Thread 0xb6923430 (LWP 6750)]
[New Thread 0xb6a23430 (LWP 6749)]
0xb6e64aac in waitpid () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  8    Thread 0xb6a23430 (LWP 6749) "mono" 0xb6e62770 in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  7    Thread 0xb6923430 (LWP 6750) "mono" 0xb6e63c50 in recv () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  6    Thread 0xb42ff430 (LWP 6754) "mono" 0xb6e608b8 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  5    Thread 0xb44b8430 (LWP 6755) "mono" 0xb6e642c0 in nanosleep () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0xb41ff430 (LWP 6756) "mono" 0xb6e629c4 in sem_timedwait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  3    Thread 0xb3e03430 (LWP 6757) "mono" 0xb6dc8a74 in epoll_wait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
  2    Thread 0xb3de3430 (LWP 6758) "mono" 0xb6e629c4 in sem_timedwait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
* 1    Thread 0xb6f3c000 (LWP 6747) "mono" 0xb6e64aac in waitpid () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0

Thread 8 (Thread 0xb6a23430 (LWP 6749)):
#0  0xb6e62770 in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x001fff10 in mono_sem_wait (sem=0x2f523c, alertable=1) at mono-semaphore.c:119
#2  0x0017db28 in finalizer_thread (unused=<optimized out>) at gc.c:1073
#3  0x001625b4 in start_wrapper_internal (data=0xdf3048) at threads.c:643
#4  start_wrapper (data=0xdf3048) at threads.c:688
#5  0x001f5c30 in thread_start_routine (args=0xd9e368) at wthreads.c:294
#6  0x00204268 in inner_start_thread (arg=0xd9e35c) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#7  0xb6e5bc00 in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#9  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 7 (Thread 0xb6923430 (LWP 6750)):
#0  0xb6e63c50 in recv () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xb6e630b4 in __pthread_enable_asynccancel () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x000d0638 in recv (__flags=0, __n=1231934123, __buf=0xb6922e83, __fd=3) at /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/socket2.h:45
#3  socket_transport_recv (buf=0x123, len=11) at debugger-agent.c:1085
#4  0x000d6ecc in transport_recv (len=11, buf=0xb6922d58) at debugger-agent.c:1475
#5  debugger_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at debugger-agent.c:9139
#6  0x001f5c30 in thread_start_routine (args=0xd9e3f8) at wthreads.c:294
#7  0x00204268 in inner_start_thread (arg=0xd9e3ec) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#8  0xb6e5bc00 in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#9  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#10 0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 6 (Thread 0xb42ff430 (LWP 6754)):
#0  0xb6e608b8 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x001df938 in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=0x40a, timeout=0xb42fe838, alertable=1, poll=<optimized out>) at handles.c:1586
#2  0x001f2a70 in WaitForSingleObjectEx (handle=0x1f2a70, timeout=3076096, alertable=1034) at wait.c:198
#3  0x00160344 in mono_wait_uninterrupted (thread=0xb6ab4220, multiple=0, numhandles=1, handles=0xb42fe89c, waitall=0, ms=99, alertable=1) at threads.c:1455
#4  0x00161ed4 in ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal (this=<optimized out>, handle=0xb42fedc0, ms=99, exitContext=<optimized out>) at threads.c:1587
#5  0xb44e1abc in ?? ()
#6  0xb44e1abc in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 5 (Thread 0xb44b8430 (LWP 6755)):
#0  0xb6e642c0 in nanosleep () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xb6e630b4 in __pthread_enable_asynccancel () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x001f4e10 in SleepEx (ms=<optimized out>, alertable=162) at wthreads.c:842
#3  0x0016425c in monitor_thread (unused=<optimized out>) at threadpool.c:779
#4  0x001625b4 in start_wrapper_internal (data=0xb400cc68) at threads.c:643
#5  start_wrapper (data=0xb400cc68) at threads.c:688
#6  0x001f5c30 in thread_start_routine (args=0xd9e7e8) at wthreads.c:294
#7  0x00204268 in inner_start_thread (arg=0xd9e7dc) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#8  0xb6e5bc00 in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#9  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#10 0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 4 (Thread 0xb41ff430 (LWP 6756)):
#0  0xb6e629c4 in sem_timedwait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x001ffff0 in mono_sem_timedwait (sem=0x2f4f7c, timeout_ms=<optimized out>, alertable=1) at mono-semaphore.c:82
#2  0x00166c20 in async_invoke_thread (data=0x0) at threadpool.c:1565
#3  0x001625b4 in start_wrapper_internal (data=0xb400cc68) at threads.c:643
#4  start_wrapper (data=0xb400cc68) at threads.c:688
#5  0x001f5c30 in thread_start_routine (args=0xd9e908) at wthreads.c:294
#6  0x00204268 in inner_start_thread (arg=0xd9e8fc) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#7  0xb6e5bc00 in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#9  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 3 (Thread 0xb3e03430 (LWP 6757)):
#0  0xb6dc8a74 in epoll_wait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#1  0x00164be0 in tp_epoll_wait (p=0x2f5084) at ../../mono/metadata/tpool-epoll.c:118
#2  0x001625b4 in start_wrapper_internal (data=0x1337220) at threads.c:643
#3  start_wrapper (data=0x1337220) at threads.c:688
#4  0x001f5c30 in thread_start_routine (args=0xd9eab8) at wthreads.c:294
#5  0x00204268 in inner_start_thread (arg=0xd9eaac) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#6  0xb6e5bc00 in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#7  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#8  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb3de3430 (LWP 6758)):
#0  0xb6e629c4 in sem_timedwait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x001ffff0 in mono_sem_timedwait (sem=0x2f5004, timeout_ms=<optimized out>, alertable=1) at mono-semaphore.c:82
#2  0x00166c20 in async_invoke_thread (data=0x2) at threadpool.c:1565
#3  0x001625b4 in start_wrapper_internal (data=0x10663a0) at threads.c:643
#4  start_wrapper (data=0x10663a0) at threads.c:688
#5  0x001f5c30 in thread_start_routine (args=0xd9ebd8) at wthreads.c:294
#6  0x00204268 in inner_start_thread (arg=0xd9ebcc) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#7  0xb6e5bc00 in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#9  0xb6dc8348 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb6f3c000 (LWP 6747)):
#0  0xb6e64aac in waitpid () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000b2148 in mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=<optimized out>, ctx=<optimized out>) at mini-exceptions.c:2299
#2  0x00027af8 in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (_dummy=11, info=0xbe8e7060, context=0xbe8e70e0) at mini.c:6777
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0xb6d735f4 in strlen () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#5  0x00186f9c in mono_string_new (domain=0xda71b0, text=0x4247 <Address 0x4247 out of bounds>) at object.c:5027
#6  0xb3c6217c in ?? ()
#7  0xb3c6217c in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

No Error message is shown at all annoyingly... Whether this is a MonoDevelop issue or what I'm not sure...

[image: Error Screenshot]

I cleared the application Output when I hit the breakpoint, ran it, and the result is shown in the screenshot.

I'm happily calling into other functions in the same library in this application just fine, just this one is complaining. This is the only one which contains an Array of a Structure, so I'm assuming the issue lies here...

Not sure if you're going to need some more information to go on?

Edit: The cpp function I'm calling into is apparently;

```
#ifdef __linux__
    #define DLL
#else
    #define DLL __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall    // definition for our header
#endif

int DLL ReadAcceptorDetails (int               Number,
                             AcceptorBlock *   Snapshot)
{
int                       EndGuard ;
int                       CoinNo ;
AcceptorInterface*        Acceptor ;
AcceptorCoinInterface*    Coin ;
AcceptorCoin*             SnapshotCoin ;
char*                     CoinPointer ;

if (!InputArea) return FALSE ;

if (InputArea->Acceptors == 0)
    return FALSE ;

Acceptor = InputArea->Acceptors ;

while (--Number >= 0)
    {
    if (Acceptor->Next == 0)
        return FALSE ;
    Acceptor = Acceptor->Next ;
    }

 // If we get here Acceptor points at the required block

do
    {
    EndGuard = InputArea->EndGuard ;

    Snapshot->Unit              = Acceptor->Unit ;
    Snapshot->Status            = Acceptor->Status | (Acceptor->Flags & ACCEPTOR_INHIBIT);
    Snapshot->NoOfCoins         = Acceptor->NoOfCoins ;
    Snapshot->InterfaceNumber   = Acceptor->Interface ;
    Snapshot->UnitAddress       = Acceptor->UnitAddress ;
    Snapshot->DefaultPath       = Acceptor->DefaultPath ;
    *(int  *)Snapshot->Currency = Acceptor->Currency ;
    if (CallerVersion >= STRINGS_RETURNED)
        {
        if (BasicControl->FieldVersion >= STRING_FIELDS)
            {
            Snapshot->SerialNumber = Acceptor->SerialNumber ;
            Snapshot->Description  = Acceptor->Description ;
            }
        else
            {
            Snapshot->SerialNumber = 0 ;
            Snapshot->Description  = "" ;     // Null string
            }
        }

    if (CallerVersion >= BARCODE_ACCEPTOR)
        {                                   // Don't worry about Paylink, as this was unused
        Snapshot->BarcodesStacked   = (Acceptor->BarcodesStacked) & 0x7fffffff ;
        Snapshot->EscrowBarcodeHere = (Acceptor->BarcodesStacked) >> 31 ;
        }

    Coin = Acceptor->FirstCoin ;
    CoinPointer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(Snapshot->Coin) ;
    for (CoinNo = 0 ; CoinNo < Acceptor->NoOfCoins ; ++CoinNo)
        {
        SnapshotCoin                  = reinterpret_cast<AcceptorCoin*>(CoinPointer) ;
        SnapshotCoin->Value           = Coin->Value ;
        SnapshotCoin->Inhibit         = Coin->Inhibit ;
        SnapshotCoin->Count           = Coin->Count ;
        SnapshotCoin->Path            = Coin->Path ;
        SnapshotCoin->PathCount       = Coin->PathCount ;
        SnapshotCoin->DefaultPath     = (char)Coin->DefaultPath ;
        SnapshotCoin->PathSwitchLevel = Coin->PathSwitchLevel ;
        SnapshotCoin->FutureExpansion  = 0 ;
        SnapshotCoin->FutureExpansion2 = 0 ;

        if (BasicControl->FieldVersion >= ESCROW_FIELDS)
            {                      // Card does escrow
            SnapshotCoin->HeldInEscrow = (char)Coin->HeldInEscrow ;
            }
        else
            {                      // Card doesn't do escrow - clear old int  field
            SnapshotCoin->HeldInEscrow = 0 ;
            }


        if (CallerVersion >= STRINGS_RETURNED)
            {
            if (BasicControl->FieldVersion >= STRING_FIELDS)
                {
                SnapshotCoin->CoinName = Coin->CoinName ;
                }
            else
                {
                SnapshotCoin->CoinName = "" ;     // Null string
                }
            CoinPointer += sizeof *SnapshotCoin ;
            }
        else
            {
            CoinPointer += sizeof *SnapshotCoin - sizeof SnapshotCoin->CoinName ;
            }

        Coin = Coin->Next ;
        }
    } while (EndGuard != InputArea->StartGuard) ;

return TRUE ;
}
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code. `ByValArray` or `LPArray`?

Comment: Yeah, the last error message was my first iteration of code when I didn't include the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray , SizeConst = 256)]` Attribute... The error message I've got currently is the first one...

Comment: Well `ByValArray` and `LPArray` are quite different. I wonder why the error message would mention `LPArray` when you used `ByValArray`.

Comment: OK, that's just too confusing for me. You are now asking about multiple variants of the code, not all of which we can see. Never mind, I give up.

Comment: Sorry... As I say, the code above is identical in both cases, only I hadn't decorated the Structs and Struct array with the attributes... I've editted my Question to clarify..

Comment: Hopefully that cleared it up a bit @DavidHeffernan! Sorry to confuse you!

Comment: You've shown a stack trace but no error. And we don't know what the unmanaged code looks like. We cannot see it.

Comment: Thanks for looking again! Yeah, there's no error... MonoDevelop just spits out that stack trace with nothing else annoyingly... I've edited my question and added the function I'm calling into.... Hope that helps some more...

Comment: Why stdcall? Although I guess that's ignored on linux. I cannot believe that there's no error. Try harder to find one. Still, we don't have all the code on the unmanaged side. Perhaps the structs are translated wrongly. can you narrow it down somewhat by stripping out some of the native code. Can you debug the native code. In short, you really need to do some debugging to work out where the problem is.

Comment: SIGSEV means that there's an error in the interop. We can't tell what it is because the question only has partial information. You should debug thee problem to narrow it down. Or publish complete detail here.